# при диплое телеграмм бота постоянно получаю ошибку ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iaogram (from versions: none)

Tags: python, heroku, deploy

Помогите разобраться перепробовал уже все варианты

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iaogram (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for iaogram
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Может ты при установке через `pip` получаешь такую ошибку и деплой здесь вообще ни при чем?

Comment: Привет нет я через гит загружаю. Да и пробовал по всякому.

Comment: ну этой информации не достаточно, чтобы как-нибудь тебе помочь. Сервер настроил для работы? Ты гит клонируешь?

Comment: Укажите в requirements.txt или откуда берутся названия пакетов для подготовки окружения конкретную версию пакета iaogram

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to Вот что пишет и дальше не дает